# Call delegate function from CCCallFuncN?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Can i call a delegate function from CCCallFuncN?

Or du i have to create a function in the sam class as the animation that calls the delegate?

```
- (void) foo
{
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callDelegate:)];
}

- (void) callDelegate
{
[delegate moveDone];
}
```

Comment: The way you phrased your question is confusing. Can you say it differently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the "`self`" part in `[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callDelegate:)]`? Well, you change it for the instance of the object containing the desired function. So if your function is in `mySprite`, you write this:

```
[CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:mySprite selector:@selector(callDelegate:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a formal delegate method that is part of a protocol you are implementing, such as touch methods, accelerometer, etc., then no, you should not manually call those. They receive specific data from the system at specific times and they are not called by your own code.

If however by "delegate" you are referring your own methods that you are creating, then yes you can call those from CCCallFuncN as that is what it is designed form.

Comment: Hi!

Im refering to my own methods, but in another object.
But i cant write:
id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector([delegate moveDone]:)];

Comment: just use the name of the object instance for `target` instead of calling `self` -- this target is the instance that contains the method (selector) that you are calling

Answer (score 0):

you should use CCCallFunc for you current code.

```
CCCallFuncN for -(void)func:(id)node

CCCallFuncND for -(void)func:(id)node param:(void*)param
```

And I also have a question with it :
I use CCCallFuncND and this code work well. Anybody can tell me the reason? :

```
[CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(func1:) data:data];
//
-(void)func1:(void*)data{
}
```